# Excel: Count Occurences of Value in Rows of a Range

Tags: excel, matrix, excel-formula, boolean, row

In Excel, I need a formula that returns a vector of Boolean based on whether the row contains a specific value or not. For example, a range (n by m matrix) contains random numbers 1 to 100. I want to get a vector of Boolean based on whether the number 41 has made an appearance in the row. If the matrix is named "matrix", the result would be a vector of length `ROWS(matrix)`.

Comment: [COUNTIF(A2:A27, 41) > 0](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)?

Comment: No. Doesn't return an array of boolean.

Comment: What will you do with that array of Boolean? Will you use it in another formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MMULT(N(Range=A1),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(Range)))>0`

where `A1` contains your search value, e.g. 41.

Amend *Range* as required.

This may require committing with `CSE`, depending upon the construction within which it is employed.

As way of an example, let's assume that *Range* is here `B1:F4`, with the following values:

**40    44  41  41  40**

**44    40  40  44  44**

**44    44  43  40  41**

**43    42  44  45  45**

This part:

`B1:F4=A1`

simply returns an array of Boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE` entries as to whether each entry within the range is equal to the value in `A1` or not, i.e.:

`{FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE;FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE}`

The `N` function then coerces these Booleans into their equivalent numerical values, i.e. `TRUE`=`1`, `FALSE`=`0`, such that:

`N(B1:F4=A1)`

gives:

`{0,0,1,1,0;0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,1;0,0,0,0,0}`

We can see that 1s occur in rows 1 and 3 (in the case of row 1 more than once). Since this is a 4-row-by-5-column array, taking the matrix multiplication with a 5-row-by-1-column array (whose entries are non-zero) will produce a 4-row-by-1-column array, the entries in each row of which being subject to the laws of matrix multiplication, such that:

`MMULT(N(B1:F4=A1),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B1:F4)))`

which is:

`MMULT({0,0,1,1,0;0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,1;0,0,0,0,0},TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B1:F4)))`

i.e.:

`MMULT({0,0,1,1,0;0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,1;0,0,0,0,0},TRANSPOSE({2,3,4,5,6}))`

i.e.:

`MMULT({0,0,1,1,0;0,0,0,0,0;0,0,0,0,1;0,0,0,0,0},{2;3;4;5;6})`

which is:

`{9;0;6;0}`

Finally, we check which of these entries is non-zero, such that:

`MMULT(N(B1:F4=A1),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B1:F4)))>0`

which is:

`{9;0;6;0}>0`

gives:

`{TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE}`

Regards

Comment: I bow before you. Amazing answer. `MMULT` was not on my radar for solving this issue. Can you explain your answer, in particular I don't understand `TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(Range))`.

Answer (score 0):

[Aggregate Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df) should work.

```
=AGGREGATE(2,6,[Array]=41)
```

Comment: No. Your example returns a range of the same size as [array]. I have a n by m matrix. I want a formula that returns a vector of Boolean of size ROWS([array]).

Answer (score 0):

You may use Index formula to get an array of Boolean which you can use in another formula if you wish.

```
INDEX(A2:O2=41,)
```

Comment: No. Your example is already a row and returns a row. I want a n by m matrix that returns a Boolean for each row.

Comment: What would be the data range and the matrix range then?

Comment: The result should be a vector of length ROWS(A2:O20).